# How to determine the index size, count In MongoDB? How does an index entry look like In MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, indexing, mongodb-query

I have 10,000 entries in the collection named `persons`

Sample document entry:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "643ac01e40ec2e09a4af1f93"
  },
  "gender": "female",
  "name": {
    "title": "Ms",
    "first": "Nalan",
    "last": "Süleymanoğlu"
  },
  "location": {
    "street": {
      "number": 1258,
      "name": "Talak Göktepe Cd"
    },
    "city": "Burdur",
    "state": "Kütahya",
    "country": "Turkey",
    "postcode": 68076,
    "coordinates": {
      "latitude": "9.8436",
      "longitude": "-145.5748"
    },
    "timezone": {
      "offset": "+8:00",
      "description": "Beijing, Perth, Singapore, Hong Kong"
    }
  },
  "email": "nalan.suleymanoglu@example.com",
  "login": {
    "uuid": "43c9882e-6db8-414c-86e0-dcb519efa7b0",
    "username": "crazybutterfly880",
    "password": "1201",
    "salt": "a2BWERh0",
    "md5": "f3105dddafdf7ea7e9478c8addc9eff7",
    "sha1": "bc5c9b810273a7feaf24de8d8600d294e1ae1c51",
    "sha256": "8f03ad80983c129a691899703515617b2b312078935e92c9b88040ccd26b3ff3"
  },
  "dob": {
    "date": "1979-07-10T04:46:21.083Z",
    "age": 43
  },
  "registered": {
    "date": "2020-08-07T04:20:36.833Z",
    "age": 2
  },
  "phone": "(105)-784-4615",
  "cell": "(820)-909-3102",
  "id": {
    "name": "",
    "value": null
  },
  "picture": {
    "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/93.jpg",
    "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/93.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/93.jpg"
  },
  "nat": "TR"
}
```

I created index for `"dob.age"`.

I checked the size of the index is 60KB

I find the distinct number of records taking the `"dob.age"` into consideration:

```
test> db.persons.distinct("dob.age").length

test> 58
```

Now my question is how can I find how many entries does the index has? Does it has one entry for each age and a pointer to all the number of documents??

For example:

```
{
age: 45,
documents:["memory_address_1", "memory_address_2",..."memory_address_N"]
}
```

I am not able to explore more into the index.I just want to know how the indexes look like?

Comment: probably a btree with the pointers to memory as u mentioned?